# *ngIf is not a valid attribute name in angular 2 and above

Tags: angular

I have created a project with CLI command. The project is working fine once I am not using any angular attributes. Whenever I used any attributes it response *ngIf is not a valid attribute name in angular 2.

```
`<div ngNonBindable><ul><li *ngIf="kk"> <h2><a target="_blank" el="noopener" ref="https://angular.io/tutorial">Tour of Heroes</a></h2>  </li>  <li><h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki">CLI Documentation</a></h2> </li><li><h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://blog.angular.io/">Angular blog</a></h2></li></ul>/div>`
```

Comment: can you add your code

Comment: how do you use it?

Comment: I have resolved my code by removing ngNonBindable. Thanks for quick response Chellappan and fateme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to Remove ngNonBindable;